# НЕ модальное окно

Tags: c#, avalonia

```
public partial class blabla : Window
{
    public blabla() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Show();
    }
    public init(DateTime d1,DateTime d2)    
    {
        // принимаем даты и изменяем даты в форме;
    }
    private void onlost(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // закрываем форму;
        // Нужно вернуть измененные d1 и d2;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Добрый день, подскажите как вернуть из НЕ модального окна значения ?
Вызов делается так

```
var a = new blabla();
a.init(d1,d2);
```

Comment: Как вы вернете данные из другого класса? Вот какие есть варианты? Первое, самое очевидное, наверно, метод, который будет вызываться и отдавать некий результат; еще вариант, это использовать `IProgress`, который передается в метод (или что-то еще) и через него уже передается результат; ну и другой вариант - событие, на которое кто-то подписывается, и уже через него идет обмен данными. Как  видите, самые стандартные варианты, которые применимы везде, выбирайте, внедряйте. Только вы не должны хотеть из формы передавать в форму, не пихайте логику в UI, это плохо, отделите ее, прочтите про MVVM.

Comment: Подпишитесь на `a.Closing`, не?

Comment: Самое главное - это определить, куда вернуть. Вот в этом объекте и создайте переменную, в которую blabla будет записывать результат ("измененные d1 и d2"), а ссылку на неё передавайте через "blabla.init".

Comment: @aepot ну да на a.Closing я само собой подпишусь мне не ясно как вернуть значения , возврат же не в init будет а где ? наверно в onlost при закрытии окна ? тогда он не должен быть void ? я вот тут торможу .

Comment: Через публичные поля/свойства окна

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я пока mvvm не понимаю смысл , там вроде предполагается что сбор данных отделяется от отображения и не отвлекает внимание так те 5 строчек сбора данных и так не отвлекают внимание . Мне надо разобраться с немодальными окнами и привыкнуть думать по другому а потом уж mvvm.

Comment: @aepot а как это написать через публичные поля ? я только вижу некрасивый вариант в blabla создать  вызывающий класс чтобы получить доступ к полям вызывающего класса . Как-то некузяво , можно делать invoke , но я еще не смотрел есть ли это в авалонии .

Comment: MVVM не про "отвлечение", а про грамотное проектирование вашего проекта, где логика в одном месте, данные в другом, UI в третьем. Этот подход позволяет вам писать код быстро, лаконично, оптимизированно. Чем меньше в вашем коде связанности, тем шустрее будет разработка проекта, и сам проект у вас будет работать быстрее, вот собственно и все. Скажем так, вы сейчас учитесь есть руками, когда как я вам советую начать есть столовыми приборами сразу, минуя кучу ошибок. Вот для вас трудно в понимании `<TextBox Text = "{Binding Text}"/>`? Думаю нет, ну а раз так, смысл познавать изначально неверное?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ конечно вы правы , но это чуть попозже .

Comment: У меня нет цели вас переубедить, заставить писать правильно, или еще что-то, просто говорю, что то, что вы сейчас делаете, неверный подход изначально, стоит об этом помнить. А так, я вам самым первым комментарием написал что делать, но вы это почему-то проигнорировали... Вы сейчас сильно зациклились на окнах и всем остальном, абстрагируйтесь от всего, от авалония, окон, и прочего. Вот у вас есть два класса, вам надо из класса А передать данные в класс Б, как поступите? Подсказку выше я вам уже дал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы просто вернуть:

```cs
class D1d2 {
  public DateTime d1, d2;
  public D1d2(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2) { d1 = dt1; d2 = dt2; }
}
public partial class blabla : Window {
  D1d2 _d1d2;
  DateTime _d1, _d2;
  public blabla() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Show();
  }
  public init(D1d2 dt) {
    // принимаем даты и изменяем даты в форме
    _d1 = dt.d1; _d2 = dt.d2; // получаем значения куда-то
    _d1d2 = dt; // сохраняем ссылку на переменную
  }
  private void onlost(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // закрываем форму;
    // Нужно вернуть измененные d1 и d2;
    _d1d2.d1 = _d1; _d1d2.d2 = _d2; // забираем значения откуда-то 
    this.Close();
  }
}
...
var a = new blabla();
var b = new D1d2(d1, d2); // это получатель
a.init(b);
```

А чтобы известить получателя, что пришёл возврат, нужно использовать callback метод:

```cs
public partial class blabla : Window {
  Action<DateTime, DateTime> _d1d2;
  public blabla() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Show();
  }
  public init(DateTime d1, DateTime d2, Action<DateTime, DateTime> ad) {
    // принимаем даты и изменяем даты в форме
    // получаем значения куда-то
    _d1d2 = ad; // сохраняем ссылку на callback метод
  }
  private void onlost(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // закрываем форму;
    this.Close();
    // Нужно вернуть измененные d1 и d2;
    _d1d2(d1, d2); 
  }
}
...
public void callback(DateTime d1, DateTime d2) {
 // это возврат
}
var a = new blabla();
a.init(d1, d2, callback);
```

Конечно, если callback в форме и что-то требуется на ней менять, то его нужно вызывать через Invoke формы.

На замечание **aepot** нужно переделать так:

```cs
public partial class blabla : Window {
  Action<DateTime, DateTime> _d1d2;
  // мне кажется, нужно сохранить оригинальный конструктор,
  // чтобы конструктор форм VS работал 
  public blabla() { InitializeComponent(); }
  // это альтернативный конструктор с параметрами 
  public blabla(DateTime d1, DateTime d2, Action<DateTime, DateTime> ad) {
    InitializeComponent();
    // принимаем даты и изменяем даты в форме
    // получаем значения куда-то
    _d1d2 = ad; // сохраняем ссылку на callback метод
  }
  private void onlost(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // закрываем форму;
    this.Close();
    // Нужно вернуть измененные d1 и d2;
    _d1d2(d1, d2); 
  }
}
...
public void callback(DateTime d1, DateTime d2) {
 // это возврат
}
var a = new blabla(d1, d2, callback); // создаём форму и передаём нужное
a.Show(); // отображаем форму
```

Comment: Добавил вариант с callback методом.

Comment: ага буду смотреть , а callback имеется ввиду метод в вызывающей форме к которому делать invoke в вызываемой форме перед закрытием тогда да этот вариант рабочий .

Comment: `this.Show()` в конструкторе - так себе история, нарушает процесс инициализации окна.

Comment: @aepot это нужно было вопрос прокомментировать, я весь код не проверял, ответил только на вопрос.